# Drawing a graph with words instead of points in Latex

Tags: latex, tikz

I am trying to draw a graph in Latex that shows the trade of between flexibility and interpretability of different machine learning methods. I attached an image of the exact graph to this question. I am struggling to get information on how to create this graph using latex. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at tikz

Comment: I have tried tikz. It doesn't seem to be able to produce a plot similar to the above one. I created the picture in Excel and imported a snippet of the necessary picture.

Comment: if you would show us what you have tried in tikz, I'm sure we could fill in the missing bits

Comment: @HeinThetard TikZ **is** _able to produce a plot similar to the above one_ ;)

Answer (score 1):

My sketch:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily %
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0) -- (10,6) -- (0,6) -- cycle;
\draw (1,0) -- (1,-0.2);
\draw (9,0) -- (9,-0.2);
\draw (0,0.6) -- (-0.2,0.6);
\draw (0,5.4) -- (-0.2,5.4);
\node at (1,-0.5) {Low};
\node at (9,-0.5) {High};
\node at (5,-1.5) {Flexibility};
\node at (-0.5,0.6) [rotate=90] {Low};
\node at (-0.5,5.4) [rotate=90] {High};
\node at (-1.5,3) [rotate=90] {Interpretability};
\node at (1.5,5.4) [color=blue,align=center] {Subset Selection\\Lasso};
\node at (3.7,4.2) [color=blue,align=center] {Least Squares};
\node at (5.5,3.0) [color=blue,align=center] {Generalized Additive Models\\Tree};
\node at (8.2,1.8) [color=blue,align=center] {Bagging, Boosting};
\node at (7.2,0.8) [color=blue,align=center] {Support Vector Machines};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and its output:

[image: screenshot of output picture]

Refining the code just a bit, but same output:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily %
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0) -- (10,6) -- (0,6) -- cycle;
\draw (1,0) -- (1,-0.2);
\draw (9,0) -- (9,-0.2);
\draw (0,0.6) -- (-0.2,0.6);
\draw (0,5.4) -- (-0.2,5.4);
\node at (1,-0.5) {Low};
\node at (9,-0.5) {High};
\node at (5,-1.5) {Flexibility};
\node at (-0.5,0.6) [rotate=90] {Low};
\node at (-0.5,5.4) [rotate=90] {High};
\node at (-1.5,3) [rotate=90] {Interpretability};
\begin{scope}[color=blue,align=center]
\node at (1.5,5.4) {Subset Selection\\Lasso};
\node at (3.7,4.2) {Least Squares};
\node at (5.5,3.0) {Generalized Additive Models\\Tree};
\node at (8.2,1.8) {Bagging, Boosting};
\node at (7.2,0.8) {Support Vector Machines};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```